# Is there any technical advantage of actionListner attribute over action attribute in h:commandButton?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, action, actionlistener, commandbutton

In the core JSF book (page 312) the author said about that:

> Note that an action alone cannot implement that behavior—an action can
>   navigate to the appropriate page, but it cannot determine the
>   appropriate page because it knows nothing about the image button in
>   the user interface or the mouse click.

below is the index.xhtml and the ManagedBean used on that example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
      <title>#{msgs.indexWindowTitle}</title>
   </h:head>

   <h:body>
      <span class="instructions">#{msgs.instructions}</span>
      <h:form>
         <h:commandButton image="/resources/images/mountrushmore.jpg" 
                          styleClass="imageButton"
                          actionListener="#{rushmore.handleMouseClick}"
                          action="#{rushmore.navigate}"/>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Managed Bean:

```
package com.corejsf;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
   // or import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped; 
   // or import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean // or @Named
@RequestScoped
public class Rushmore {
   private String outcome = null;
   private Rectangle washingtonRect = new Rectangle(70, 30, 40, 40);
   private Rectangle jeffersonRect = new Rectangle(115, 45, 40, 40);
   private Rectangle rooseveltRect = new Rectangle(135, 65, 40, 40);
   private Rectangle lincolnRect = new Rectangle(175, 62, 40, 40);

   public void handleMouseClick(ActionEvent e) {
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      String clientId = e.getComponent().getClientId(context);
      Map<String, String> requestParams 
         = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

      int x = new Integer((String) requestParams.get(clientId + ".x")).intValue();
      int y = new Integer((String) requestParams.get(clientId + ".y")).intValue();

      outcome = null;

      if (washingtonRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
         outcome = "washington";

      if (jeffersonRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
         outcome = "jefferson";

      if (rooseveltRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
         outcome = "roosevelt";

      if (lincolnRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
         outcome = "lincoln";
   }

   public String navigate() {
      return outcome;
   }
}
```

I dont understand why the author said that, as i tried to use only the action attribute and make a binding to the commandButton, so i modified the index.xhtml and managed bean like that:

New index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:head>
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
      <title>#{msgs.indexWindowTitle}</title>
   </h:head>

   <h:body>
      <span class="instructions">#{msgs.instructions}</span>
      <h:form>
         <h:commandButton image="/resources/images/mountrushmore.jpg" id="commandButton" binding="#{rushmore.command}"
                          styleClass="imageButton" ac
                          action="#{rushmore.navigate}"/>
      </h:form>
      <ui:debug></ui:debug>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

New Managed Bean:

```
package com.corejsf;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
// or import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UICommand;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean
// or @Named
@RequestScoped
public class Rushmore {
    private String outcome = null;
    private Rectangle washingtonRect = new Rectangle(70, 30, 40, 40);
    private Rectangle jeffersonRect = new Rectangle(115, 45, 40, 40);
    private Rectangle rooseveltRect = new Rectangle(135, 65, 40, 40);
    private Rectangle lincolnRect = new Rectangle(175, 62, 40, 40);
    private UICommand command;

    public String navigate() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String clientId = command.getClientId(context);
        Map<String, String> requestParams = context.getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap();

        int x = new Integer((String) requestParams.get(clientId + ".x"))
                .intValue();
        int y = new Integer((String) requestParams.get(clientId + ".y"))
                .intValue();

        outcome = null;

        if (washingtonRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
            outcome = "washington";

        if (jeffersonRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
            outcome = "jefferson";

        if (rooseveltRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
            outcome = "roosevelt";

        if (lincolnRect.contains(new Point(x, y)))
            outcome = "lincoln";

        return outcome;
    }

    public UICommand getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    public void setCommand(UICommand command) {
        this.command = command;
    }
}
```

So the application worked exactly how it shoul work.
My question is what is the **technical advantage** (as i know that from a conceptual point of view we must separate business logic from user interface logic) of using actionListner in that example instead of using only action attribute?

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382 If not, please update your question to elaborate how that answer was insufficient.

Comment: @BalusC I read that answer before i posted the question, but i saw that you said about the reasons for using actionListner : "and/or to have access to the component which invoked the action (which is available by ActionEvent argument)". So i just whant to understand if there is any technical reasons for using actionListner in the example above

Comment: Nope. It's purely for demonstration purposes. It would only be beneficial if the `outcome` part was determined in `action` instead of in `actionListener`. Right now the `handleMouseClick()` action listener isn't reusable on different actions expecting a different outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered whithin the comments, So i will copy the response of BalusC:

> Nope. It's purely for demonstration purposes. It would only be
>   beneficial if the outcome part was determined in action instead of in
>   actionListener. Right now the handleMouseClick() action listener isn't
>   reusable on different actions expecting a different outcome